# Create a 2D spline-based Terrain in Unity3D

Tags: unity, 2d, terrain, terrain-rendering, side-scroller

[image]

I want a 2d terrain in Unity that can be edited in Scene view. I have come across a github repository which nearly serves my requirements, but I am not sure what exactly I can do to make it have another texture on the top layer to create an illusion of the platform.

I have searched extensively and didn't find any methods to do this. I am not looking for Paid solutions like Ferr2D, Zippy Terrain 2D Terrain Creator etc.

I want the the terrain to be able to have curves and splines etc.

Comment: You can use Unity's own 2D TileMap. Complete tutorial: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation/intro-2d-world-building-w-tilemap

Comment: Is an EdgeCollider2d what you're talking about?

Comment: The EdgeCollider2d is what you want to look into. You provide a series of vertices to define the line segments.

Comment: not really, I understand that it can work for a short time. But what if I want to have a curvy bumpy random road and want it in an infinite runner game. I want a system where I can create it through script and through scene. Just like Unity's 3D Terrain

Comment: [Unity has recently released an experimental preview feature that would help with this, called SpriteShape](https://twitter.com/rustumscammell/status/975799312897556481).

Comment: The road in hillclimb racing is also made out of triangles as any other model